# Why I can't print the salary out?

Tags: c++

I'm programming a quasi database.

I have a class Pair:

```
class Pair{
    MyString m_key;
    Data* m_data;
}
```

Then the method AddItem composes the pair and adds it into the database.

```
Data Ivanov(1, 10, "Manager", 100000);
Data Petrov(2, 20, "Manager", 200000);
MyString* employee0 = new MyString("Ivanov");
MyString* employee1 = new MyString("Petrov");
bd.AddItem(employee0, &Ivanov);
bd.AddItem(employee1, &Petrov);
```

The database itself monitores the number of elements and the capacity.
    class Bd{
        private:
            int m_size; 
            int m_capacity; 
            Pair** ar;
            ...
    }

If the we add an item, the database stretches if the capacity has overflowed.
If we remove an item, an empty cell occurs which may be used in future.
This is done in order not to fragment the heap too much.

```
void Bd:: AddItem(MyString* key, Data* data){
    if (m_size < m_capacity){
        *ar[m_size+1] = Pair(key, data);
    }
    else{ 
        if (m_size == 0){
            ar = new Pair*[++m_size];
            m_capacity++;           
            ar[0] = new Pair(key, data);
            stop
        }
        else{
            Pair** tmp = new Pair*[++m_size];  
            m_capacity++;
            memcpy(tmp, ar, m_size * sizeof(Pair*));
            delete[] ar;
            ar = tmp;
            ar[m_size-1] = new Pair(key, data);
            stop
        }
    }
}


void Bd::RemoveItem(const char* a_key){
    Pair** tmp_ar = this->get_ar();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++){       
        Pair* tmp_key = tmp_ar[i];
        MyString* tmp_my_string= (*tmp_key).get_m_key();
        const char* tmp_str = (*tmp_my_string).GetString();
        if ( strcmp(tmp_str, a_key) == 0){
            delete ar[i];           
            for (int j = i; j < m_size-1; j++){
                *ar[j] = *ar[j+1];
            }
            delete ar[m_size-1];
            m_size--;
            break;
        }
        stop
        if (i == (m_size-1)){
            cout << "No such person." <<endl;           
        }
    }   
    stop
}
```

Well, now I wan to use the bd.

```
cout << bd;
bd.Print("Ivanov");
bd.Print("Petrov");
```

**It works perfectly. It prints either the whole database or any element as well.**

Then I remove Mr. Ivanov.
bd.RemoveItem("Ivanov");

Now I have problems with either of this:

```
bd.Print("Petrov");
cout << bd;
```

I have a printing method in the class Data.

```
void Data:: print_info(){   
    cout << "Sex: " << this->getSex() << ", age: " << age <<", position: " << position <<", salary: ";
    cout << salary << endl; 
}
```

I have specially made a second cout because this is where I have got troubles.
The salary though it is clearly visible in the scope, causes the whole problem.
Please, have a look at this picture:

[image]

If I make one more step, I get the error about a corruption of the heap.
The output window shows: HEAP: Free Heap block 296b30 modified at 296b58 after it was freed

Could you help me understand why I can't print this salary?

Comment: I don't see any cats in your code...

Comment: You would do a lot better by using a free database like SQLite or MySql rather than writing your own.

Comment: try this change `*ar[j] = *ar[j+1];` to `ar[j] = ar[j+1];` in `RemoveItem`

Comment: BTW use vectors for this. it will be a whole lot easier.

Comment: Is that a square screen?

Comment: @user2280716, tried. It hasn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following problems in `AddItem()`:

```
void Bd:: AddItem(MyString* key, Data* data){
    if (m_size < m_capacity){
        *ar[m_size+1] = Pair(key, data);
    }
```

If `m_size` is less than `m_capacity`, you add a new item but do not increase `m_size`

```
    else{ 
        if (m_size == 0){
            ar = new Pair*[++m_size];
            m_capacity++;           
            ar[0] = new Pair(key, data);
            stop
        }
```

I assume you meant to check against `m_capacity` being 0.

```
        else{
            Pair** tmp = new Pair*[++m_size];  
            m_capacity++;
            memcpy(tmp, ar, m_size * sizeof(Pair*));
            delete[] ar;
            ar = tmp;
            ar[m_size-1] = new Pair(key, data);
            stop
        }
```

Your `memcpy` is copying from `ar`, which had a size of `m_size` before you incremented `m_size`, but now has a size of `m_size-1`, so you've copied past the end of your array.

And the following issue in `RemoveItem()`:

```
if ( strcmp(tmp_str, a_key) == 0){
    delete ar[i];           
    for (int j = i; j < m_size-1; j++){
        *ar[j] = *ar[j+1];
    }
    delete ar[m_size-1];
    m_size--;
    break;
}
```

Your `delete ar[m_size-1]` is deleting an item that you've just moved to `ar[m_size-2]`. You don't want to delete this.

I'm thinking this delete might be part of your problem. Specifically, I think the following 2 changes will help:

1. Change the `*ar[j] = *ar[j+1]` line to `ar[j] = ar[j+1]` as mentioned in a comment.
2. Get rid of the `delete ar[m_size-1];` line. As with the `ar` line change, you definitely don't want this.

This won't solve all the issues, but it will make sure that you haven't deleted `Petrov` before trying to call his `print_info()` method.

Comment: I agree about the m_size in the very beginning. As for the last paragraph, I really want to delete this because I have already made a copy (*ar[j] = *ar[j+1];). Well, this all is very well, but it hasn't help to understand why I can't print the salary which I can see in the scope.

Comment: I agree. I had some concerns that the delete in `RemoveItem` was causing the `cout` issues, but I don't think that's it. If I get a chance to have a closer look, I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is the whole project (lab3.rar): https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!167&authkey=!AGkZQPKd8GFq5vQ